# In CivilMail for 4.6.2 how do I prevent duplicate emails?

Tags: civimail

Since 4.6.2 CiviMail is sending every email twice. I'm enclosing an attachment to show. The report also shows the successful delivery at 200% on some emails and 300% on others.

http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36345.0.html

Comment: I'm having the same problem with civimail after upgrading 4.5.6 -> 4.6.2. All intended recipients are receiving a duplicate message 30 minutes after the first. The civicrm cron job runs every 15 minutes. Thoughts please?

Comment: How do you run the cron? via php-cli or via http?

Comment: I have just experienced this same problem with mailing job being sent twice. I have switched off the scheduled job to not send out any more and have read these pages: http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,36345.0.html https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16251 https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16281 How can I clean the job queue so when I turn the mailer process back on no more emails will go out and how do I stop it doing it again in the future? Cheers, Dave

Comment: Ok - I think I may have more information that can help solve this issue. When sending a bulk email with only 1 distribution list, it works correctly. If I send a bulk email with multiple distribution lists/contact groups, and a contact is only multiple lists, then they get multiple emails during the bulk email processing. Prior to 4.6.2 there used to be a check box on the bulk email creation form to check to not send duplicate emails. This button was removed from the form and I bet that's why the system sends mutliples to the same contact now.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug related to smart groups and premature mailings, which is now fixed in version 4.6.3.

See https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16251